# Acesso a valor de propriedade

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue.js-2

Tenho um método onde preciso pegar o número de cada mesa, mas, o retorno é sempre o comprimento da propriedade e não o seu valor. Se deixo apenas uma mesa o método retorna corretamente o valor da propriedade, porém se adiciono mais mesas no objeto, o retorno será o comprimento de mesas que existem.

```
let app = new Vue({

    el: '#app',
    data: {
        tituloApp: 'Acompanhamento de mesas',
        escolhaMesa: 'Escolher a mesa',
        mesas = {

            idMesa: {
                consumo: [
                    {
                        nome: 'suco maracujá',
                        quantidade: 1,
                        valor: 5.50
                    },
                    {
                        nome: 'guaraná coca-cola',
                        quantidade: 1,
                        valor: 3.00
                    },
                    {
                        nome: 'feijoada',
                        quantidade: 2,
                        valor: 12.00
                    }
                ],
                numMesa: 1
            },

            idMesa: {
                consumo: [
                    {
                        nome: 'água',
                        quantidade: 2,
                        valor: 2.50
                    },
                    {
                        nome: 'guaraná fanta-uva',
                        quantidade: 2,
                        valor: 3.00
                    },
                    {
                        nome: 'porção de frios',
                        quantidade: 2,
                        valor: 23.50
                    }
               ],
               numMesa: 2
            }
        },

        methods: { 
            MostraMesa: function(mesa) {
                let idMesa = this.mesas.idMesa.numMesa;   // retorna o length
            }
        }
})
```

HTML:

```
<div id="mostra-mesa">
    <div>
        <p>{{ produtos }}</p>
        <ul>
            <li v-for="nomes in mesas">{{ nomes.consumo.nome}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>{{ quantidade }}</p>
        <ul>
            <li v-for="consumos in mesas">{{ consumos.consumo.quantidade }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>{{ vlrUnit }}</p>
        <ul>
            <li v-for="valores in mesas">{{ valores.consumo.valor }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>{{ vlrTotal }}
            <input type="number" readonly v-model="vlrConta" @click="MostraMesa">
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*mesas* deve ser um array, não pode usar idMesa de forma repetida as chaves deve ser única em cada objecto

**Forma errada**

```
mesas={
       idMesa:{}, //está repetir a chave
       idMesa:{}
       }
```

**Forma correcta**

```
mesas=[
       {idMesa: 1}, 
       {idMesa: 2}
       [
```

Sugiro que crie uma propriedade *mesaAtual* por forma a saber qual o índice da mesa atualmente seleccionada

Nos métodos deve criar funções que retornem valores (não é o caso no seu exemplo)

```
let app = new Vue({

      el: '#app',
      data: {
        tituloApp: 'Acompanhamento de mesas',
        escolhaMesa: 'Escolher a mesa',
        mesas = [{
            consumos: [{
                nome: 'suco maracujá',
                quantidade: 1,
                valor: 5.50
              },
              {
                nome: 'guaraná coca-cola',
                quantidade: 1,
                valor: 3.00
              },
              {
                nome: 'feijoada',
                quantidade: 2,
                valor: 12.00
              }
            ],
            numMesa: 1
          },
          {
            consumos: [{
                nome: 'água',
                quantidade: 2,
                valor: 2.50
              },
              {
                nome: 'guaraná fanta-uva',
                quantidade: 2,
                valor: 3.00
              },
              {
                nome: 'porção de frios',
                quantidade: 2,
                valor: 23.50
              }
            ],
            numMesa: 2
          }
        ],

        methods: {

          obterIdMesa(mesa) {

            return this.mesas[mesa].numMesa;
          }

        }

      })
```

**Exemplo: v-for**

```
<ul>
   <li v-for="mesa in mesas"> 

        Mesa: {{ mesa.numMesa }}

        <ul>
           <li v-for="consumo in mesa.consumos"> 

            Consumo: {{ consumo.nome }}, Qt:{{ consumo. quantidade}}

           </li>
       </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Jorge. Editei a pergunta, tinha esquecido de passar a função dentro do método. Vou refazer meu objeto como vc mostrou e testar para ver.

Comment: Se funcionar por favor confirme a resposta

Comment: Cara então, não estou conseguindo trazer mais nada nesta estrutura aí, como faço por exemplo para listar a propriedade **nome** de uma mesa em um `v-for`?

Comment: <li v-for="mesa in mesas">
    {{ mesa.numMesa }}
 </li>

Comment: Rsrsr... desculpa aí cara sou novo com **Vue**, como faço para pegar nome dentro de consumos fiz: `<li v-for="nomes in mesas"> {{ nomes.consumos.nome }} </li> ` mas não trás nada, só as bullets das li.

Comment: Tem dois arrays mesas e consumos tem que fazer dois for uma para cada array e um dentro do outro

Comment: Po aí se quer me ferrar né Jorge kkkkkk.... sei lá como faz isto, no html mesmo dá para fazer, for dentro de for? Na documentação do Vue não vi nada parecido.

Comment: Veja adição na reposta

Comment: Vou editar a minha pergunta e adicionar o html tbm, pois é aí que estou me perdendo, na estrutura html.